# Angularjs web app inside a static website

Tags: angularjs

I'm working on some web app in AngularJS. But could i create a website first with some information about the app? And inside the same domain using a login that will send the users to the angular app?

So the app should only be loaded when the user wants to log in or register. Otherwise the static website should be visible.
Is there any documentation on this topic.?

Or do i need to create something like `info.mydomain.com`

Additional information

On the index page i do this like any regular Angularjs app

```
    <body ng-app="app">
    <div ui-view=""></div>


Load all scripts
```

Where should i load all the script files if i don't use the index as the start of my web app?

Comment: You can you distinct static page whicl will include all bundles(js files) with your angular app. for example: You have www.mysite.com, server provides static index.html, you need create www.mysite.com/app and the server will provide app.html with angular. It should be work.